# Why is Mule exception strategy so chatty?

Tags: exception, mule

In my Mule app, I've configured some of the flows to use a catch exception strategy in order to do some special processing. For these cases, I want to pop the error and the original payload into an object store. Everywhere else, the default exception strategy is fine.

```
<flow name="saveLookup">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"  ref="Lookup_Save_VM" />
    <component>
      <spring-object bean="insertLookupMDCvalues"/>
    </component>
    <set-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[payload]"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.company.LookupData"/>
    <set-variable variableName="transactionId" value="#[payload.transactionId]"/>
    <transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN">
        <logger message="${lookup.SQL}" level="INFO"/>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="saveLookup" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="JdbcConnector" />
        <foreach collection="#[payload.transactional.lookupItems.items]">
            <logger message="${lookup.item.SQL}" level="INFO" />
            <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="saveLookupItem" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="JdbcConnector"/>
        </foreach>
    </transactional>
    <component>
      <spring-object bean="clearLookupMDCvalues"/>
    </component>        
    <catch-exception-strategy>
        <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation">
            <add-message-property key="errorMap" value="#[['id' : transactionId, 'body' : originalPayload, 'error' : exception.summaryMessage]]"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <choice>
            <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['resubmit']]">
                <logger message="Resubmission of lookup data failed, saving to Dead Letter object store. ID=#[transactionId]" level="INFO"/>
                <objectstore:store config-ref="lookupDeadLetterOS" key="#[transactionId]" overwrite="true" value-ref="#[errorMap]"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <logger message="Saving lookup data failed, saving to Error object store. ID=#[transactionId]" level="INFO"/>
                <objectstore:store config-ref="lookupErrorOS" key="#[transactionId]" overwrite="true" value-ref="#[errorMap]"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <set-payload value="Error: #[exception.summaryMessage]"/>
        <component>
          <spring-object bean="clearLookupMDCvalues"/>
        </component>                 
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

My problem is that when an error is encountered, let's say a Null Pointer Exception in the foreach component, I'm seeing four ERROR log statements for each event:

- Exception stack is: 1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException) *...and so on. This is logged twice.*
- CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy - Message : Execution of the expression "payload.transactional.lookupItems.items" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: LookupData
- DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy - Message : Execution of the expression "payload.transactional.lookupItems.items" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: LookupData

I thought that a flow-specific exception strategy should override the default strategy. Why the duplicate log messages, and is there a way to shush them? I'd like to avoid having to configure the default exception strategy, as it's perfectly acceptable behavior in the majority of the flows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the built in exception strategies inherit from `AbstractExceptionListener`, and they all use the `logException` template method.  The base implementation always logs at ERROR level, which is sometimes not appropriate for your application.

You can create a simple subclass of CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy that overrides the logException method, and logs however you want.  Then, use it in your flow in place of the `<catch-exception-strategy>` like so:

```
<custom-exception-strategy class="com.mycompany.mule.QuietCatchExceptionStrategy">
    <!-- your message processors here -->
</custom-exception-strategy>
```

Comment: This worked for me, with the added step of wrapping all the processors within the `<catch-exception-strategy>` in a `<processor-chain>`. It still seems excessive to have both log identical, verbose messages, but, c'est la vie.